# Android sqlite Cursor.getCount() always return 1

Tags: android, sqlite

I know Cursor.getCount() returns number of columns that's it . I have written a code i can't see where i am making mistake. Please help me I have wasted 4 hours in it .

```
Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select count(*) from "+TABLE_NAME+" WHERE SENDERS_EMAIL = '"+email+"' AND FRIENDS_STATUS = 1;",null);

    Log.d("FrindsInDb","FriendExists, count="+res.getCount());
```

Explanation:
case 1:
if `email = princy@gmail.com` , then output -> `res.getCount()` returns `1` (CORRECT)
case 2:
if `email = princy@gmail.c` , then **ALSO** output -> `res.getCount()` returns `1` (WHY ?)

in my table under `SENDERS_EMAIL`, only `princy@gmail.com` exists

Comment: res.getCount() will return no. of rows.
Since you are asking for count(*) it will always return 1 row, whether data exist or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

select `count(*)` always returning 1 row. Remove count method from your query.

So Select all rows from table then getCount from cursor.

```
    Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from "+TABLE_NAME+" WHERE SENDERS_EMAIL = '"+email+"' AND FRIENDS_STATUS = 1;",null);

    Log.d("FrindsInDb","FriendExists, count="+res.getCount());
```

Comment: thanks for the sonic speed answer, but can you also tell me , why was count(*) was returning 1 ?

Comment: its returning number of rows of table in one column and one row :)

Comment: okay , but as per my question in Case 2 , the email was invalid , its still returning 1 . Does that mean count(*) will return 1 irrespective of the wrong email or wrong Column value that i provided with WHERE clause?

Answer (score 2):

res.getCount() will return no. of rows. Since you are asking for count(*) it will always return 1 row, whether data exist or not

proper code will be

```
Log.d("Result",res.get(0));
```

here res.get(0) have no. of rows

Comment: Dear Trush your answer is right. But its very different than question line

Comment: Dear Amy, I think question was why its always returning one, thats what I explained. and give him the proper way of utilizing the response. hope you like my answer too.

Comment: @Trush , thanks for helping me out. But can you tell me where did you find this method Cursor.get(int a) . I can't find in Android Api docs in this link : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html

Answer (score 0):

You are using

```
Log.d("FrindsInDb","FriendExists, count="+res.getCount());
```

Here `res.getCount()` will always return how many rows are there.

Answer (score 0):

cursor.getCount(), return the rows of the result; so, your sql "select count(*) from table" ,which result only one row. you can get count with "select * from table", else you can use "cursor.